# How to solve J2ME java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/lwuit/layouts/Layout error?

Tags: java-me

My midlet and DB java pages doesn't show any error but,while running the emulator it loads and suddenly terminated with following error...

Please help me to  solve

```
Running with storage root C:\Users\Acer\j2mewtk\2.5.2\appdb\MediaControlSkin
Running with locale: English_United States.1252
Running in the identified_third_party security domain
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/lwuit/layouts/Layout
    at com.sun.midp.midlet.MIDletState.createMIDlet(+29)
    at com.sun.midp.midlet.Scheduler.schedule(+52)
    at com.sun.midp.main.Main.runLocalClass(+28)
    at com.sun.midp.main.Main.main(+80)
Execution completed.
3409264 bytecodes executed
25 thread switches
1683 classes in the system (including system classes)
17718 dynamic objects allocated (532816 bytes)
3 garbage collections (458688 bytes collected)
```

Comment: were you able to include the LWUIT classes in your jar?

Answer (score 0):

add the  **LWUIT.jar** file in your build path.

After adding clean and build then test your application